# Connect with ssh to your localhost

Tags: linux, ssh

```
$ l
total 24K
drwxr-x---  2 maik users 4.0K Dec 28 11:19 .
drwxr-x--- 38 maik users 4.0K Dec 28 11:22 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 maik users  392 Dec 28 11:18 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 maik users 1.8K Dec 28 11:09 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 maik users  391 Dec 28 11:09 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 maik users 1.1K Dec 28 10:58 known_hosts
```

I have generated `id_rsa` with `ssh-keygen` + a keyphrase.

I have copied the contents of `id_rsa.pub` to `authorized_keys`

I did `ssh-add`

When I try to connect to `ssh localhost` it switches to ssh `maik@localhost` but I am unable to login with my keyphrase.

Do I have to do something else?

```
$ ssh -v localhost
OpenSSH_7.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2e 3 Dec 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/maik/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/maik/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/maik/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/maik/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/maik/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/maik/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/maik/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/maik/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'maik'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:KfpWyOPnPr5kDDHkaPHGjFVzxYrGW9uVBWJuFYOP3Rk
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/maik/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/maik/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/maik/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/maik/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/maik/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
maik@localhost's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
maik@localhost's password:
```

Comment: added the reason why it probably fails. If not, please add the lines relevant to sshd in sshd log (`/var/log/auth.log`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I try to connect to ssh localhost it switches to ssh maik@localhost but I am unable to login with my keyphrase.

You entered the passphrase during the step `ssh-add` so you don't have to enter it once more, if you have `ssh-agent` working. The "switching" is probably the sign that it works. You can verify it by running `echo $SSH_CLIENT`, which should write "where are you connected from".

But I have no idea what you mean by the second part of the sentence. Can you be more precise and verbose what do you want and what does happen?

Your authorized keys need to have different permissions. The file should not be readable by anyone else. You can fix it using `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: Added additional logs and `echo $SSH_CLIENT` returns nothing.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it with the logs. It seems that I needed to add my username to 'AllowUsers' in my ssh config.

Comment: deos it work for you now or do you have any other problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can switch the user by running:

```
sudo su - <desired_user_name>
```

to change the user you want to be e.g. `sudo su - jenkins`

Other issues you may encounter but not strictly relevant to this ticket:

a) permissions of public key needs to be max 600

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

b) being able to ssh with password: edit (`sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config`) and change "PasswordAuthentication no" to "PasswordAuthentication yes" then restart sshd deamon bh running

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

c) pass public key to remote host via ssh-copy-id:

```
ssh-copy-id <user>@<host_IP>
```